# Create multiple storyboard iPhone/ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

Create multiple storyboard iPhone/ipad,use the same viewcontroller,but iPhone storyboad can run,iPad error message(can run on ios simulator,but can't not run on my ipadair).

this is my code:

```
NSBundle *resource = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LibraryResource" ofType:@"bundle"]];
[resource load];

    UIUserInterfaceIdiom userIdiom = [[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom];
    if (userIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        UIStoryboard* mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPad" bundle:resource];
        LibraryController* LibraryController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LibraryController"];
        [self presentViewController:LibraryController animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else if (userIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        UIStoryboard* mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:resource];
        LibraryController* LibraryController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LibraryController"];
        [self presentViewController:LibraryController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
```

error message:

```
 2014-03-04 14:24:25.515 AddLibrary[311:60b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x157e0aad0 </var/mobile/Applications/184A78F9-1488-4C34-AD5C-10170067ACEA/AddLibrary.app/Library9898API Resource.bundle> (not loaded)
 2014-03-04 14:24:25.522 AddLibrary[311:60b] Unknown class LibraryController in Interface Builder file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included your file to your target that is your app bundle. Ensure you have checked the target membership.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have checked the target membership

Answer (score 0):

add your view controller to your build phases.

1. Clean and rebuild it again. It should work.
2. If not then reset the simulator then try
3. Rename your view controller files and class name and then add it your project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

iPadAir must support (64-bit),use the old project not change

[image]